# Toast Message not working android

Tags: android, android-toast

I have 2 classes BlockIdActivity.java and ScanWifi.java. I have 2 buttons in BlockIdActivity.java file and i am able to see my toast defined there. However i cant see the toast for the button i defined in ScanWifi.Java class.

Following is the code for BlockIdActivity.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class BlockIdActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private ImageButton mUpButton;
private ImageButton mDownButton;
private TextView mBlock_Id_Field;
int counter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_block_id);

    mUpButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.arrow_up);
    mDownButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.arrow_down);
    mBlock_Id_Field = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.BlockIdField);


    mUpButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (mBlock_Id_Field.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
         {
                counter = 1;
                mBlock_Id_Field.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
         }
            else {
                counter = Integer.valueOf(mBlock_Id_Field.getText().toString().trim());
                counter++;
                mBlock_Id_Field.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
            }

        }
        });

    mDownButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int counter = Integer.valueOf(mBlock_Id_Field.getText().toString().trim());
        //  boolean emptyfield = mBlock_Id_Field.getText().toString().equals("");  

            if(counter <=1 ){
                Toast.makeText(BlockIdActivity.this,
                        R.string.negative_blockid_toast,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                counter = 1;
                mBlock_Id_Field.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
            }else {
                counter--;
            mBlock_Id_Field.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
            }

        }
    });
    }
```

}

and code for ScanWifi.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ScanWifi extends ActionBarActivity {

    private Button mScanWifiButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_block_id);

        mScanWifiButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ScanWifiButton);
        mScanWifiButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                        R.string.ScanWifi_toast,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

    });

    }

}
```

This is the strings.xml file :

```
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">SnifferTrain</string>
    <string name="BlockId">BlockId</string>
    <string name="ScanWifi">ScanWifi</string>
    <string name="ScanWifi_toast">ScanWifi Button Pressed</string>
    <string name="negative_blockid_toast">Block Id Field Cannot Be Less Than 1 or Empty.Setting BlockID To 1</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>

</resources>
```

Can someone please explain why ScanWifi_toast does not show when i press ScanWifi Button. I have tried changing the context of the toast to ScanWifi.this or getApplicationContext() but it doesn't seem to work. I don't get any compilation errors. Please help

Comment: change `R.string.ScanWifi_toast` to `getResource().getString(R.string.ScanWifi_toast)`

Comment: always try to define name in lowercase instead uppercase in String.xml more detail check : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling

Comment: Despite all the answers so far, there's an overload of `Toast.makeText()` that accepts a string resource id and it works all right. The problem is somewhere else. Consider adding logging or a debugger breakpoint to your code to first confirm it is run, and if not, figure out why it is not run.

Comment: @laalto : Yes, i have tried the suggestions but i still do not see the toast. I will try what you have suggested.

Comment: Looking at the two files, I see you say it works when you do `Toast.makeText(BlockIdActivity.this` but fails when you do `Toast.makeText(getBaseContext()`. Is this a hint? Do you get an error message in your LogCat?

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say your `ScanWifi` activity has not been run at all. Note that your activities are both using the same layout but you're only assigning a click listener to the scan button in the other activity.

Comment: @KenY-N : I get an error saying Style contains key with bad entry: 0x01010479. I am not sure what this means. I have checked my ScanWifi_toast string and it seems to look ok?

Comment: @laalto : Can you please elaborate on that? Do think it is problem with this mScanWifiButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()? If so then what is the solution?

Comment: How are you lauching the `ScanWifi` activity in the first place?

Comment: @laalto : I am just executing the whole code as an android application? Is this what you mean? Do i have to call ScanWifi class in BlockIdActivity.java by a constructor or something?Sorry if this is silly. I am very new to java and android

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem with your string file. Do like other way:

```
Toast.makeText(ScanWifi.this,getResource().getString(R.string.string.ScanWifi_toast),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `ScanWifi` activity code is not run. Hence the click listener is not registered to a button on screen and therefore the toast is not seen.

Since both your activities are using the same content view layout, you should probably move the `findViewById()` and `setOnClickListener()` to the main activity.

To launch other activities, use an `Intent`, e.g.

```
startActivity(new Intent(context, ActivityName.class));
```

Comment: If i move findViewById() and setOnClickListener() to the main activity then most of the code for ScanWifi.java class is moved to the mainactivity file? In that case i can just create  another button along with the 2 which are already there and implement the same logic with it. The reason i put findViewById() and setOnClickListener() in a seperate  ScanWifi.java class was to keep all the widgets separate, since scanwifi will become more complex in future. I just need it to work from within ScanWifi.java for now? Can you please show me how to start the ScanWifi activity?

Comment: If you want another activity with another layout, you can do it, just use another layout name in `setContentView()`. Use the `startActivity()` with `ScanWifi.class` to start it.

Comment: I actually want to use the same layout for ScanWifi.class. Is it possible to use the same layout but start different activities for blockidactivity and scanwifi activity like i had attempted initially?

Answer (score 0):

Use this for `Toast` message

```
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                    getResource().getString(R.string.ScanWifi_toast),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be :

```
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),getResource().getString(R.string.ScanWifi_toast), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Because `R.string.ScanWif`i_toast dont automatically return the `String` you put in your XML, it only return the `id`.

Answer (score 0):

you should use `getString(R.string.ScanWifi_toast)` in place of directly using `R.string.ScanWifi_toast`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Toast.makeText(context, context.getString(R.string.ScanWifi_toast), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"xyz",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

or

```
Toast.makeText(Activity.this,string,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: You can take Ur String Values in side toast directly ... or Assign in String that value after that use in Toast...